# Why doesn't tkinter see a defined variable

Tags: python, tkinter

While running my program, I get into a problem. With the 'save3' function I get the following error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Medion\Desktop\PY - DOS GUI\OKNO.py", line 59, in save3
    d = pliktyped.get()
NameError: name 'pliktyped' is not defined
```

I am giving here an excerpt of the function:

```
def save():
    def save3():
        d = pliktyped.get()
        typed = str(d)
        plik = open(plek, 'w')
        plik.write(typed)
        menu()
    def save2():
        plek = str(pliksave.get())
        plik = open(plek, 'w')
        textsave2 = Label(okno, text="Text to be typed").grid(column=0, row=0)
        pliktyped = Entry(okno, width=10)
        pliktyped.grid(column=0, row=1)
        goSave2 = Button(okno, text="Type this text to file", command=save3).grid(column=1, row=1)
        
    for widget in okno.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    foldery = Label(okno, text=folder, bg='lightblue').grid(column=0, row=3)
    folderyCo = Label(okno, text='Files:', bg='lightblue').grid(column=0, row=2)
    textsave = Label(okno, text="File to edit:").grid(column=0, row=0)
    pliksave = Entry(okno, width=10)
    pliksave.grid(column=0, row=1)
    goSave = Button(okno, text="Edit this file", command=save2).grid(column=1, row=1)
```

It is probably a basic mistake of a novice programmer, but thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You could use `global`.

Comment: All variables created by assigning a value to them in a function will be local to that function unless you declare them `global` or `nonlocal` as the case may be.

Answer (score 0):

because of different namespace. You set it in save2, while try to access in save3

use either `return` from save2 or consider using `nonlocal`

Comment: It crossed my mind, but I wasn't sure if I would write the code correctly. But thank you for your answer too!

Answer (score 0):

It is because `pliktyped` is a local variable inside `save2()` and it cannot be accessed inside `save3()`.

Actually you can reuse `textsave`, `pliksave` and `goSave` inside `save2()` and `save3()` instead of creating new widgets inside `save2()` since they are put in same cells of the initial created widgets:

```py
def save():
    def save3(plek):
        with open(plek, "w") as plik:
            plik.write(pliksave.get())
        menu()

    def save2():
        plek = pliksave.get()
        textsave.config(text="Text to be typed")
        goSave.config(text="Type this text to file", command=lambda:save3(plek))
        
    for widget in okno.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    Label(okno, text=folder, bg='lightblue').grid(column=0, row=3)
    Label(okno, text='Files:', bg='lightblue').grid(column=0, row=2)

    textsave = Label(okno, text="File to edit:")
    textsave.grid(column=0, row=0)

    pliksave = Entry(okno, width=10)
    pliksave.grid(column=0, row=1)

    goSave = Button(okno, text="Edit this file", command=save2)
    goSave.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought something was wrong with the local variable. However, thank you so much for your help!